# calculate volume from point coordinate in javascript

Tags: javascript, geometry, spatial, volume

how to calculate volume in javascript from arbitrary points coordinate array like this one?

```
const points = [
  [0, 1, 0],
  [1, -1, 1],
  [-1, -1, 1],
  [0, -1, -1]
]
```

i've used the scipy.spatial.convexHull library to calculate volume, but i can't use python on my react js app, thus i need a javascript library that can perform the similar functionality. thanks in advance

Comment: You can try [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/delaunay-triangulate).

Answer (score 1):

[This JavaScript library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/delaunay-triangulate) performs the Delaunay triangulation in arbitrary dimension. So you can use the same way I show you in [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70366109/how-to-calculate-volume-of-irregular-shapes-in-python/70382397#70382397).

Here I do it with Node:

```
var triangulate = require("delaunay-triangulate")

const vertices = [
    [0.,0.,0.], [0.,1.,0.1], [1.,1.,0.1], [0.,1.,0.], 
    [0.,0.,1.], [0.,1.,1.1], [1.,1.,1.1], [0.,1.,1.] 
];
 
const tetrahedra_indices = triangulate(vertices);
 
var tetrahedra = new Array(tetrahedra_indices.length);

for(let i = 0; i < tetrahedra.length; i++){
    const indices = tetrahedra_indices[i];
    tetrahedra[i] = [
        vertices[indices[0]],
        vertices[indices[1]],
        vertices[indices[2]],
        vertices[indices[3]]
    ];
}

const array1_minus_array2 = (arr1, arr2) => ( 
    arr2.map(function(num, idx){ return num - arr1[idx] })
);

const det3x3 = arr => (
    arr[0][0] * (arr[1][1]*arr[2][2] - arr[1][2]*arr[2][1]) -
    arr[0][1] * (arr[1][0]*arr[2][2] - arr[1][2]*arr[2][0]) +
    arr[0][2] * (arr[1][0]*arr[2][1] - arr[1][1]*arr[2][0])
);

const volume_tetrahedron = tetrahedron => {
    const a = tetrahedron[0];
    const b = tetrahedron[1];
    const c = tetrahedron[2];
    const d = tetrahedron[3];
    const matrix3x3 = [
        array1_minus_array2(a, d),
        array1_minus_array2(b, d),
        array1_minus_array2(c, d)
    ];
    return Math.abs(det3x3(matrix3x3)) / 6;
};

const volumes = tetrahedra.map(volume_tetrahedron);

const volume = volumes.reduce( (a,b) => a + b );

console.log(volume);
// 0.5166666666666667
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, it really works and the volume value is exactly like what scipy.convexhull calculated. once again thank you so much

Comment: but how to learn the math behind it, though? do you have any sources or pdf that easy to learn? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library to do matrix manipulation in JavaScript. It is lightweight and popular.
[gl-matrix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gl-matrix)

Comment: how to calculate volume using that library? is there any math formula that can i use?